# Formatting long-form survey data in R

Tags: r

We asked 3 people two or three yes-no questions. Let me denote these 3 people by 101,102,103 the questions by "A", "B","C" and the responses by 0, 1. The result is

```
q<-data.frame(response=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1),
                     qstn=c("A","B","A","B","A","B","C"),
                     person=c(101,101,102,102,103,103,103))
```

We need to convert this table to the following format

```
person|qustionA|questionB|questionC
101   |   0    |    0    |   NA
102   |   1    |    0    |   NA
103   |   0    |    1    |   1
```

Comment: You want to do to two things here: a) reshape long-form to wide-form, transforming the 'qstn' variable and b) format that output into fixed-width with '|' separators and spaces. Tou can use something like `capture.output(write.table(..., sep='|', quote=F))` for b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reshape` from base-r:

```
reshape(q, v.names="response", idvar="person",
        timevar="qstn", direction="wide")

  person response.A response.B response.C
1    101          0          0         NA
3    102          1          0         NA
5    103          0          1          1
```